# Change padding on fancybox depending on image width

Tags: fancybox, width, padding, dimensions

I am new to javascript and jQuery and am trying to make a slideshow using Fancybox.
The problem is that I want the images to display on a box of the same size regardless of whether they are portrait or landscape images. My images are all either 700 X 525 for landscape or 525 X 700 for portrait.

The way I have it the landscape images load like it is showed on the top of the image below, the portrait images load as shown in the middle, and I want the portrait images to load as shown on the bottom, with the box with the same dimensions as if it were landscape:

[image]

I think what I should do is change the left padding depending on the image dimensions but I have no idea how.

Thank you for your help in advance.

I am using Fancybox version: 2.1.4 and I have set the defaults as such:

```
        padding : 15,
        margin  : 20,

        width     : 800,
        height    : 600,
        minWidth  : 100,
        minHeight : 100,
        maxWidth  : 9999,
        maxHeight : 9999,

        autoSize   : true,
        autoHeight : false,
        autoWidth  : false,

        autoResize  : true,
        autoCenter  : !isTouch,
        fitToView   : true,
        aspectRatio : false,
        topRatio    : 0.5,
        leftRatio   : 0.5,
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this post is 11 months old, but I thought I would share my solution in case it helps someone else out in the future.

Basically I have set a min-width css attribute onto the fancybox element and am comparing that against the current image width, if it is smaller I am adding padding to the fancybox element so that the fancybox element stays the same width but the image inside is horizontally centered.

Step 1: in your css set a min-width on the fancybox element. This is the width that you want your fancybox element to stay at regardless of image width.

> .fancybox-wrap {  min-width: 1120px; }

Step 2: add in the afterLoad function when you call fancybox

```
$(".fancybox").fancybox({ 
    afterLoad: function(current) {
        var $el = $(".fancybox-wrap").eq(0);    // grab the main fancybox element
        var getcurrwidth = current.width;       // grab the currrent width of the element
        var getdesiredwidth = $el.css('min-width'); // grab our min-width that we set from the css

        var currwidth = Number(getcurrwidth);
        var desiredwidth = Number(getdesiredwidth.replace('px', ''));


        if (currwidth < desiredwidth)
        {
            var custompadding = (desiredwidth - currwidth) * 0.5; // if the width of the element is smaller than our desired width then set padding amount
            this.skin.css({'padding-left': custompadding+'px', 'padding-right': custompadding+'px' }); // add equal padding to the fancybox skin element 
        }
    }
});
```